# Passing an Instance of an Object to a Method that takes an Action<> as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In Dot Net Core convention for configuring services is as follows.

> Method that Requires Action<> As Parameter

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAsResourceServer(this IServiceCollection services, Action<AuthMiddlewareOptions> action = null)
{
     if(action != null)
     {
         AuthMiddlewareOptions authOptions = new AuthMiddlewareOptions();
         action.Invoke(authOptions);
     }
     ...
     return services
}
```

This allows us to configure our service in startup as follows.

> Startup ConfigureServices Method

```
services.AddAsResourceServer((a) =>
{
    a.Audience = "Long Audience";
    a.Issuer = "provider.com/oauthprovider";
});
```

This is really cool! I like this pattern. It works very well for allowing anyone to overwrite base configuration options.

However this seems very cumbersome when you already have an instance of the object. How would I create an instance of an object, convert it to an action, and pass that to the `.AddAsResourceServer` method?

> I have tried:

```
Action<AuthMiddleWareOptions> auth = new Action<AuthMiddleWareOptions>()
/// The above way still requires a "target" in constructor so it doesnt work.
///so i still need to pass each 
///property into it.
```

My consumers of the service may have just created an instance of AuthMiddleWareOptions and populated through appsettings!

> They may have done something like this.

```
AuthMiddlewareOptions myoptions = new AuthMddlewareOptions();
Configuration.Bind("AuthMiddlewareOptions", myoptions);
```

Now that they have 'myoptions'. Is there a quick way to use that with the Action Parameter. Maybe like this?

```
AuthMiddlewareOptions myoptions = new AuthMddlewareOptions();
Configuration.Bind("AuthMiddlewareOptions", myoptions);
services.AddAsResourceServer((a) => SpecialThing(myoptions));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a problem. The last bit of code you've written is valid. There's no obligation to use the parameter passed in by Action, you could just ignore it and use myoptions from closure like you've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply bind your configuration to the options instance provided by the method.

```
services.AddAsResourceServer(options => 
{
    Configuration.Bind("AuthMiddlewareOptions", options);
});
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. If I need to save the options, I can save them within the AddAsResourceServer Method.

Answer (score 1):

You may register multiple configuration delegates for a single option class:

```
services.Configure<AuthMiddlewareOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AuthMiddlewareOptions"));

services.AddAsResourceServer(options => SpecialThing(options));
```

And *AddAsResourceServer* should call `services.Configure`, as well:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAsResourceServer(this IServiceCollection services, Action<AuthMiddlewareOptions> action = null)
{
    if (action != null)
        services.Configure(action);


    // ...

    return services;
}
```

Having this setup, *AuthMiddlewareOptions* is populated from the configuration section "AuthMiddlewareOptions", then the customization delegate (*SpecialThing*) has a chance to change the options filled at the previous step.

It's important that **the order matters**! If you swap the two lines, *SpecialThing*'s  changes will be overwritten by the values coming from the configuration.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying, I am not trying to change the `AuthMiddlewareOptions` object. I just want to use it as is, passed to the ``AddAsResourceServer` method. "Special Things" was just a placeholder for what I needed to do to the `AuthMiddlewareOptions` object to get it to be passed into the `AddAsResourceServer` method. I see what you are saying if I did want to make changes to `AuthMiddlewareOptions` but I do not.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your point. However, options doesn't work that way in .NET Core. **It's the responsibility of the framework to create actual option objects.** (Just take a look at the [sources](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsFactory.cs#L39).) We have the *IConfigureOptions<TOptions>* interface to setup these object instances. The various overloads of *services.Configure* registers implementations of this interface in the DI container under the hood.

Comment: Consumers of your service shouldn't create option objects, they should register configurers as shown in my answer. Of course, if you stick to using the Options API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it the other way arround.

I use for example the `AddAuthorization` since I do not find your method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(c =>
{
    c.DefaultPolicy = null;
});
```

This can be configured using the following method:

```
public static void Config(AuthorizationOptions configure, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    configure.DefaultPolicy = null;
    //Configuration.Bind("AuthMiddlewareOptions", myoptions);
}
```

That way you can do:

```
services.AddAuthorization(c => Config(c, Configuration));
```

The problem is, that in these `Action<T>` methods you get the object `T`, which is already instantiated. So you need to copy the custom created object to it. With above we change the API, so it is configured on the correct object.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many patterns, it wasn't until I hovered over `a` in the method to realize that it wasnt of type `Action<AuthMiddlewareOptions>`, but it was in fact `AuthMiddleWareOptions`. so this very simple assignment worked!

```
services.AddAsResourceServer(a => a = myoptions);
```

Comment: If you didn't alter the code of *AddAsResourceServer*, this simply CANNOT work. You only change the object reference stored in parameter *a* of the lambda function, what has no effect on the object reference held by the caller method.

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer to your question "Passing an Instance of an Object to a Method that takes an Action<> as Parameter" is "no, you can't"

But as a workaround, you could simply make a deepclone of your object, to swap the properties of the "inner" options.

Something like this :

```
static class Copy
{
    public static void ObjectToAnother<T>(T source, T target)
    {
        foreach (var sourceProp in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var targetProp = target.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProp.Name);
            targetProp.SetValue(target, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

And you could use that like this :

```
var obj = new Obj();
Foo.Bar((a) =>
{
    Copy.ObjectToAnother(a, obj);
});
```

It should work

Comment: OK nice to see you solved your problem, but I think I don't deserve the "-1" as I answered your exact question wich is "Passing an Instance of an Object to a Method that takes an Action<> as Parameter"...

Comment: @kipy: you don't know who downvoted you, and it is best not to try to guess. Voting here is anonymous by design (except to Stack Overflow database admins).

Comment: @halfer : Yes, you're right. I just wasn't familiar enough with SO in that time :)